# The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCR120.dlI was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

Tags: php, wamp, php-5.6, windows-11

The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCR120.dlI was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
i reinstall it but still wamp server not working on windows 11

i try to download all vs codes and still didnt work

Comment: I think this has to do with configuration file. What exactly are you trying to do that prompted this error?

Comment: You are not seriously still using PHP 5.6 ...? (If you do, then please hover over the tag above, to see how massively outdated that is.)